# Force nuget to always update a dependency

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I wish to ensure my nuget package always updates to the latest version of another dependent package.  Is there anyway I can do this?

My current nuspec looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>Engine</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>Engine</title>
    <authors>AgResearch</authors>
    <owners>Overseer </owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>My budget model</description>
    <releaseNotes>Release model</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2014</copyright>
    <tags>Overseer engine</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="OverseerEngine.Schema" version="" />
      <dependency id="Rezare.Lib" version="1.0.23.2" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="OverseerEngine.dll" target="lib\net40\OverseerEngine.dll" />
    <file src="OvrFileImport.dll" target="Content" />   
  </files>
</package>
```

It is the **OverseerEngine.Schema** package that I wish to always be updated (if an update is available) whenever this package is.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is not an automated way to do this. User has to manually update the package using the console or the update tab of manage nuget packages dialog.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I actually got around it by making the necessary min version of the schema the same as this package version.  Seems to work sort of.  Cheers.